# After adding bootstrap to datatables colvis dropdown stopped working

Tags: django, datatables

i am working on a django project where i am using datatables, and i am trying to beautify it by using bootstrap. It works as expected colvis dropdowns show the columns without a problem but when i add bootstrap i can't see the columns to filter in dropdowns there is no explanation or errors on the console. I wonder if anyone had the same problem before and how did you solve it?
Thanks

[Colvis dropdown image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jggc9.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was using :
https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.6.5/css/buttons.dataTables.min.css
and change it to :
https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.7.0/css/buttons.bootstrap4.min.css
Problem is not a version problem it was a css problem.